# Public Private RSA Key Generation In angular 6+

Tags: angular8

I am looking for a library that can generate RSA keys programmaticly on login within my angular app,
The angular public key will be used to request data from the server and the server will convert its AES encrypted saved data to public key encrypted RSA data and send it to the angular app where the user can decrypt select data on request.

I have tried the 'kepair' node module but it does not conform to x.509 standards for public key that my Java Spring boot app requires for RSAPublicKey creation for encryption.

If anyone has some suggestions to help me solve this it would be greatly appriciated